# WCF RESTful Console-hosted, return 400 Bad Request

Tags: wcf, rest, console, host

Studying WCF RESTful, host in a Console,

my steps:

1. create sample models
2. create contract of service
3. create service
4. host this service in a console.
5. run this host, looks ok.
6. create a winform, use service address via json post to service host.
7. i hope it would work, but return http 400.

I tried on WCF(not REST) Console-hosted, WebAPI, steps all ok.

finally, stackoverflow.com

please help

**Models**

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class Building
{
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Manufacturer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Furniture : Building
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Reception
{
    public int Floor { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Room : Building
{
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public List<Furniture> Furnitures { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Hotel : Building
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }

    public List<Reception> Receptions { get; set; }

    public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IHotel
{
    // Create objct Hotel
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST", RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool Create(Hotel hotel);
}
```

**Service**

```
public class HotelService : I Hotel
{
    public bool Build(Models.Hotel hotel)
    {
        if (hotel == null)
            return false;

        // codes here is object hotel(EF) creation, test OK
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Host(Console)**

```
WebServiceHost serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Demo.Services.HotelService), new Uri("http://192.168.1.101/HotelService"));
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Demo.Contracts.IHotel), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
sdb.HttpHelpPageEnabled = false;

Console.WriteLine("Starting Service...");
// start service
serviceHost.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Started, press RETURN to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();
serviceHost.Close();
```

**Client(Winform)**

Caller

```
public bool BuildHotel(string json)
{
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.101/HotelService");

    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); // 400 throwed here
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

    return true;
}
```

Json String for 'bool BuildHotel(string)' upon

```
{
    "Guid":"ea59c011-d656-4870-b29b-30a44e668560",
    "Receptions":[
        {"Floor":1,"Number":1},
        {"Floor":2,"Number":2}
    ],
    "Rooms":[
        {
            "Number":"c",
            "Furnitures":[
                {"Name":"1","Manufacturer":{"Name":"1","Telephone":"1"}},
                {"Name":"2","Manufacturer":{"Name":"2","Telephone":"2"}}
            ],
            "Manufacturer":{"Name":"c","Telephone":"c"}
        }
    ],
    "Name":"x",
    "Address":"x",
    "Manufacturer":{"Name":"x","Telephone":"x"}
}
```

Comment: Your JSON String contains a Manufacturer element after your address element and from your Hotel Class object there is no property on it. Try removing this element and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

it expects such kind of JSON:

{"k_*BackingField":{"k*_BackingField":"4","k_*BackingField":"4"},"k*_BackingField":"x","k_*BackingField":"ea59c011-d656-4870-b29b-30a44e668560","k*_BackingField":"x","k_*BackingField":[{"k*_BackingField":1,"k_*BackingField":1},{"k*_BackingField":2,"k_*BackingField":2}],"k*_BackingField":[{"k_*BackingField":{"k*_BackingField":"3","k_*BackingField":"3"},"k*_BackingField":[{"k_*BackingField":{"k*_BackingField":"1","k_*BackingField":"1"},"k*_BackingField":"1"},{"k_*BackingField":{"k*_BackingField":"2","k_*BackingField":"2"},"k*_BackingField":"2"}],"k__BackingField":null}]}

To change it you can mark all your data contracts with DataContract and DataMember attribute:

```
    [DataContract]
    public abstract class Building
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    }
```

In this case it will understand json as you have given us in the question and will process it successfully.